# Как избежать NULL Warning в представленном ниже коде? (C#)

Tags: c#, null, warning

```
string Prompt(string message){
    Console.Write(message);
    string? elem = Console.ReadLine();
    if (elem == null){
        Prompt(message);
    }
    return elem;
}
```

Прежде чем выполнить весь код, выводит:
warning CS8603: Возможно, возврат ссылки, допускающей значение NULL

Нужно именно без этого предупреждения.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А вам надо возвращать null?

Comment: Попробуйте явное приведение сделать... вот так например `return x ?? null;` Или разделить на два случая, через if, и вернуть явно (string)x  или x.Value и явно return null. Возможно так `return ((x.HasValue)? x.Value : null);` разделить

Comment: @nick_n_a получается так?                                                                                                                string Prompt(string message){
    Console.Write(message);
    string? elem = Console.ReadLine();
    return elem == null ? Prompt(message) : elem;
} так как у строк нет атрибута Value и HasValue

Comment: `return elem!;` - так пойдёт?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov даа, спасибо Вам большое! :)

Comment: [! (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) - ссылка на документацию.

Comment: не надо `elem!`, он у вас null останется. `return elem ?? Prompt(message)` Но вообще не надо рекурсий. сделайте цикл.

Comment: Нужно четко понимать что происходит, и что может быть в вашем коде. Смотрите, вы создали метод `Prompt`, который отдает `string`, то есть некую строку, не `NULL`. Далее вы делаете `Console.ReadLine();`, который в некоторых случаях может отдать вам `null`, вот если он `null`, то какой результат должен быть возвращен вашем методом? Сейчас вы возвращаете `elem`, который, как мы выяснили, может быть `null`, это вам подходит? Если да, то делайте метод `Prompt` с возвращаемым `string?`, то есть "тип может быть `null`", если нет, то в случае `null` возвращайте из метода что-то, не `null`.

Comment: @4per спасибо Вам огромное!)